# Android EditText in child of AdapterView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I created a custom list like `ListView` with some custom functions base on `AdapterView`. Everything worked well. Except when I put an `EditText` in each child (row) of list, it is lagging and slow when scrolling. The console keep printing a lot of lines like below:

```
06-05 13:03:20.922  15836-15836/com.rerevn.listviewtest        W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
06-05 13:03:20.922  15836-15836/com.rerevn.listviewtest        W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
06-05 13:03:20.932  15836-15836/com.rerevn.listviewtest        W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
06-05 13:03:20.932  15836-15836/com.rerevn.listviewtest        W/IInputConnectionWrapper: setComposingRegion on inactive InputConnection
06-05 13:03:20.932  15836-15836/com.rerevn.listviewtest        W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
06-05 13:03:20.932  15836-15836/com.rerevn.listviewtest        W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
06-05 13:03:20.932  15836-15836/com.rerevn.listviewtest        W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
06-05 13:03:20.942  15836-15836/com.rerevn.listviewtest        W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
06-05 13:03:20.942  15836-15836/com.rerevn.listviewtest        W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: initially set editable and focusable false to edit text and check it

Comment: No output anymore but still lag and slow. When I change EditText by TextView, it very smooth